# Code Design: self resetting boolean. Reason against this?

Tags: java

I was thinking about a get method which resets itself. The construct i have actually works too. But I'm not sure if I should avoid this.
**The idea is that after the first "true" return, the value gets reseted automatically.** In this case, the get value is a boolean, which tells me if I received an answer. As soon as I get a true, the member should reset itself back to false. Otherwise I would have to do that manually. 
The following is my working get method for this idea. If the value s true, I start a new small thread which waits for 200ms and resets the member back to false. In the mean time the old value is already returned.
My question is, can/should I use it like that or are there some major reasons against it? Because somehow, I got the feeling,that this way is not to recommend.

Thank you for any inputs.

```
public boolean isAck() {
    if (acknowledged){
    Thread th = new Thread() {
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                acknowledged = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    th.start();}
    return acknowledged;
}
```

Comment: why not reset it immediately ?

Comment: Your accessors should probably not also be mutators. What do you expect your posted code to do?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish by resetting the value.  However you are spawning off a thread to reset it and you are going to come across some sort of concurrency issue if your application attempts to access isAck again.

Comment: belongs in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: if you were to set `acknowledged=true` and then call `isAck()` in a loop, could you predict which iteration would return false?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is, why I have a bad feeling with it. But I couldn't think of a different solution. 
After the first return of true, the value of acknowledge should be reseted to false.

Comment: @deanosaur
Yes you are right. It wouldn't be possible to predict it. Luckily in my case, this will not happen. But of course, it is an indicator for none clean code. I couldn't think for an other solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would do something like this -

```
public boolean isAck() {
  if (acknowledged) {
    setAck(false);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

if you don't like that approach; you might prefer

```
public boolean isAck() {
  try {
    return acknowledged;
  } finally {
    setAck(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
public boolean isAck() {
   synchronized(this) {
      boolean result = false;
      if (acknowledged){
         result = true;
         acknowledged = false;
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```